# Admin panel Voyager Laravel 7 Installation failed

Tags: laravel, package, voyager

i'm trying to install the voyager panel in my Laravel project but when i run this command Composer require tcg/voyager i got this error :  Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

This is the file of composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.22.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets try this ,

Step 1. restart your system

Step 2. run `composer global require laravel/installer`

Step 3. Create fresh laravel project using `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

avoid to use `laravel new blog`

Step 4. change terminal path to project folder and run `composer require tcg/voyager`

next follow voyager docs hope it will help you.

Comment: i  upgrade my laravel from 6 to 7 then upgrade my package to this version: 
        "tcg/voyager": "1.5.2.*"